# how to delete an image using django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to know how to add a delete button in my form for deleting an image.

The project is a simple "Pics viewer", the index shows all the images that are stored but I want to add an "x" icon for deleting that specific image.

Here is my code.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from gallery.forms import ImageForm
from gallery.models import Image

def index(request, image_form=None):
    image_form = image_form or ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if image_form.is_valid():
            new_image = Image(image=request.FILES['image_file'])
            new_image.save()
    # obtenemos el listado de imagenes registradas
    images_list = Image.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'image_form' : image_form,
        'images_list' : images_list,



    })
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='static/gallery/%Y/%m/%d')

admin.site.register(Image)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    image_file = forms.FileField(
        label='choose a file',
        help_text = 'Max 2 megabytes'
    )
```

**index.html** (It shows a list of images )

```
<style>
    ul {list-style:none; width:800px;}
    ul li {float:left; margin:6px;}
</style>
<form action="./gallery" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p> {{ image_form.non_field_errors }} </p>
    <p> {{ image_form.image_file.label_tag }} </p>
    <p> {{ image_form.image_file.help_text }} </p>
    <p>
        {{ image_form.image_file.errors }}

        {{ image_form.image_file }}
    </p>
    <p> <input type="submit" value="subir"> </p>
</form>

<h2>Im&aacute;genes</h2>
<ul>
{% for image in images_list %}
    <li>
        <img src="/{{ image.image }}" height="75" />
    </li>
{% endfor %}

</ul>
```

I want to add on index.html the delete button deleting an image :D

Answer (score 1):

urls.py

```
[.........]
url(
   r'^delete-image/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 
   'delete_image', 
   name="delete_image"
),
[.........]
```

views.py

```
def delete_image(request, id):
    image = Image.objects.get(pk=id).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:url_name'))
```

template

```
<ul>
    {% for image in images_list %}
    <li>
        <img src="/{{ image.image }}" height="75" /> 
        <a href="{% url app_name:delete_image image.id %}">Delete</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from myapp.models import Image

class ImageDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Image
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

#### urls.py

```
from myapp.views import index, ImageDelete

...
url(r'^image/(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', ImageDelete.as_view(), name="image-delete"),
...
```

#### index.html

```
{% for image in images_list %}
    <li>
        <img src="/{{ image.image }}" height="75" />
        <a href="{% url 'myapp:image-delete' image.id %}">Delete</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```