# How to delete individual files - Django 1.8

Tags: django

How does one delete individual files in Django?

Say we have a model ('Car') and some related images ('Photos')

If multiple images are uploaded for a car, how does one delete a particular image?

```
Class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharFIeld(max_length=10)
    thumbnail  = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnails/')

Class Photos(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

We could get all of the images for the car with a query like this:

```
(queryset=Photos.objects.filter(car_id = pk))
```

but what if we only want to delete a single image - how do we get the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to write a custom function [allows you to delete individual images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824958/how-to-delete-an-image-using-django). This may not be the best option but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over a forloop.

```
queryset=Photos.objects.filter(car_id = pk)
for img in queryset:
    img.delete()
```

or if you want to delete first image, then;

```
queryset[0].delete()
```

Comment: This will delete all of the related images, right? I am asking how to get an individual image for deletion - assuming you do not know the images postition in the queryset

Comment: Apply if condition in for loop, if you know which one to delete.

Comment: What if you don't know the image id, if you know what I mean? You see a set of images and you want to delete one - is there a way to get some kind of unique id for the image and pass it to a delete method?

Comment: That's what i am asking, how you identify the image?

Comment: I don't know...Say there is a list of cars, and each car has two images. Say you want to delete the second image on one of the cars - how would you do it? Sorry for the simple question

Comment: try:queryset[1].delete() except:pass